# Interpreting MLLib's linear regression o/p‏

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I use LIBSVM format to specify my input feature vector, which used 1-based index. When I run regression the o/p is 0-indexed based. I have a master lookup file that maps back these indices to what they stand or. However, I need to add offset of 2 and not 1 to the regression outcome during the mapping. So for example to map the index of 800 from the regression output file, I look for 802 in my master lookup file and then things make sense. I can understand adding offset of 1, but not sure why adding offset 2 is working fine. Have others seem something like this as well?

Answer (score 1):

LIBSVM input format is 1-based. However, the coefficients/weights that you get at the end of the regression simply match with the total number of features you had, there is 1 to 1 correspondence between the two.